# Is it possible to move the minimap?

Tags: dota-2

As title says, been trying to ask on the Dota-2 ingame chats with no success.

Can this be done? For long time League of Legends players like me, one gets used to have the minimap on the lower right corner, so it would be nice to move Dota's minimap to the same place.

Comment: I saw a hackjob of it a few days ago that involved modifying local files, but I can't find it any more. =/

Comment: If it pops up again I'll post an answer.

Comment: Coming from SC2. one of the first things I did in LoL was moving the minimap to left :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain, coming from LoL or not, I have the same feeling that map is in the wrong position and too big for my taste (misclicks when retreating to Radiant base are frequent) but unfortunately Dota 2 minimap size and position cannot be modified at the moment.

Both possibilities have been already requested on Dota 2 dev forum [[SUGGESTION] Option to change minimap to right side](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=7481), but there is no official answer from Valve devs yet.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't** valve is in hurry to develop Dota 2 and they wont be adding less important things like this anytime soon.

And since game is only in beta there aren't any good mods or 3rd party scripts to change that.

As Drake mentioned there is a petition on dota forums to add that option an it has a nice number of supporters,so it is possible they add the option before final release of the game.

There is only 1 popular mod out there(for now) that changes dota 2 a bit,but it still doesn't have the option to change minimap location,and the stability is terrible it crashes the game and with every beta update half the things stop working.

In case you have problems with clicking on minimap by accident you can change dota_minimap_misclick_time which is basically the time that you have to hover your mouse over the minimap before you can click it. I think the default value is 0.4.
Just write in console: **dota_minimap_misclick_time "TIMEINSECONDS"**

Comment: This is wrong, people have done so, albeit sort of a hack job.

Comment: You can modify interface of any game anyhow you want especially games on source engine(official editing tools),anyone who knows a bit of editing can do it for himself...thing is that no one seems to find good mod/tutorial and there is a lot of people looking for it.

Comment: @Decency If for "hacking jobs" you mean DLL injection or similar things I don't think they are seen very well by Valve and its VAC system. It is definitively feasible then, but it can also lead to undesired side effects; what Arremer (and me) is looking for is a (VAC) accepted way.

Comment: @Drake No, I just mean it's not official or very good. I'm pretty confident that it's legal, but you may be right.

Comment: @Arremer yeah this was one of those, just can't recall where I saw it done.

Answer (score 1):

Go in options in the settings of dota and under the minmap area click draw map on the right

Comment: Draw a map? Do you mean move map?

Comment: No, he's correct. The setting in the options menu, which was added last year, is indeed labelled "Draw Minimap on Right". If you're the one that downvoted his answer, please undo it. It is correct. 

Reference: http://www.neutralcreeps.com/2014/04/how-to-transfer-dota-2-minimap-to-right.html